# How to recursively read all characters in a list?

Tags: python, recursion

I need to write a function to recursively read all chars in a file and append to a list.The function needs two parameters , the file and the list. Recursion is stumping me.Any tips on thinking recursively I appreciate as well.
Bellow is the code I have written to print the chars of a list , without recursion.

```
def newChar(usrFile,usrList):

    for line in usrFile:
        for c in line:
            usrList.append(c)

    print(usrList)


def main():
    usrFile = open("input.txt",'r')
    usrList = []
    newChar(usrFile,usrList)



main()
```

Result :

```
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd', ' ', 'p', 'r', 'i', 'n', 't', ' ', 'a', 'l', 'l', ' ', 't', 'h', 'e', 's', 'e', ' ', 'c', 'h', 'a', 'r', 'a', 'c', 't', 'e', 'r', 's', '.']
```

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: There is a lot of information out there on recursion. Have you tried looking up a few guides and tutorials on it?

Comment: Thanks, updated with my current code.I don't want someone to simply write my code. I want to learn the steps they would go through.

Comment: BTW. Is it a school assignment? This task is such inherently iterative (do something _for each_ character in file) that to be honest it's hard for me to imagine why someone would want to write recursive solution for it.

Comment: Your code still makes no attempt at recursion.  "Recursion is stumping me" is not a specific problem description.  There are myriad explanations and examples of recursion in this group, on this site, and on the Internet.  What aspect aren't you getting?

Comment: To jump-start the basics ... a recursive routine checks first to see whether it's done: say, **if end_of_file: return None**.  Otherwise, the routine does something trivial, a single step toward the solution.  Then it removes that step from the remaining work and dumps that remainder into a call to itself.  For instance, "Chop the first character off the input.  Call myself to handle the rest of the input.  Append that one character to the returned list, and then return this new list to whatever called me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to think about recursion is to try and solve only a small piece of the problem, and then imagine that recursive call 'magically' solves the rest of the problem.  Importantly, you have to consider what happens when the rest of the problem is trivial to solve; this is called the **base case**.

In this case, the small piece we can solve in one recursive call is reading a single character (byte).  The base case occurs if there were no characters left in the file; when this happens, you append nothing to the list and just return what you already have built up.

This idea can be implemented as follows.

```
f = open('test_file.txt', 'r')
char_list = []

def read_rec(fh, chars):
    curChar = fh.read(1)
    if curChar: #returns False at the end of the file
        chars.append(curChar) #append to chars
        return read_rec(fh, chars) #recursively read the rest of the file
    return chars

print read_rec(f, char_list)
```

## Output

```
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd', ' ', 'm', 'y', ' ', 'n', 'a', 'm', 'e', ' ', 'i', 's', ' ', 'G', 'a', 'r', 'r', 'e', 't', 't', '\n']
```

Comment: Very helpful, thank you. I think the place where I was getting stuck at was how to create a list out of the file without using a for loop.Also im still confused on how this is moving through the file, wouldnt it have to be incremented to move to the next line?

Comment: If you haven't already, I'd suggest running the code with a really simple input file (two or three chars) and use the pdb library and set_trace to set some breakpoints so you can see what's going on with the chars list at every recursive call.